# FFTW Error "Symbol not found: _ompi_mpi_char" when running executable

Tags: c++, fftw

I'm on macOS Catalina (10.15.7) and I have FFTW installed using `brew install fftw`. Up until today, I was able to run an executable which required FFTW. I have no idea why it just stopped working today and gave me the following error.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _ompi_mpi_char
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/fftw/lib/libfftw3_mpi.3.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/opt/fftw/lib/libfftw3_mpi.3.dylib
zsh: abort      ./cartogram -h
```

I've tried everything from uninstalling and reinstalling all my brew packages and git cloning a fresh repo from GitHub but it doesn't work despite it working for my friend when he freshly clones the repo from GitHub. My suspicion is that it has something to do with my "macOS Catalina 10.15.7 Update" 2 days ago, which is 1 day after I last successfully ran my executable.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be due to the formula's flag [`--enable-openmp`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/fftw.rb#L40). I have tried to compile FFTW 3.3.10 myself using the following command to configure:

```sh
./configure --enable-threads --enable-shared --disable-debug --disable-dependency-tracking --enable-avx2
```

and then

```sh
make && make install
```